# PostgresException: 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host <IP address>, user "<username>", database "<database>", SSL on

Tags: .net, postgresql, azure, asp.net-core

I have a postgresql database on Azure for testing purposes. It was working fine until yesterday. It started to give error like

> PostgresException: 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "", database "", SSL on

I have tried to change pg_hba.conf file from/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf via Azure Cloud Shell but I could not find that file exactly. It only shows me this directory:
[image]

Comment: You are listing /usr/lib/postgresql, not /var/lib/pgsql/data

Comment: Thank you for the answer but there is no /var/lib/pgsql/data directory. It leads me nowhere.

Comment: I wouldn't expect /var/lib to exist on windows, but then again wouldn't expect /usr/lib to either.  What is your OS?  How did you install PostgreSQL?

Comment: @jjanes hi, windows OS on Azure. I did not install postgresql explicitly.

Comment: Then is this an azure-managed database?  That is going to be different than just renting the hardware/OS from azure and installing the database yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This configuration file is to help extensions and client programmed compile and link against PostgreSQL. It shows only binary information.   The **pg_hba.conf** file can appear in many places, depending on how PostgreSQL was installed. The standard location will be in the database's data directory.
**[/home, /var/lob/pgsql, /var/lib/postgresql/[version]]**

To find the path of the "pg_hba.conf" file use this command

```
sudo -u postgres psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'show hba_file';
```

for more information refer this [tutorial](http://www.thegrimmscientist.com/postgres-host-based-authentication/) blog